# Where is the Firefox Cache?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-cache

With all the big changes with Firefox recently, all the info about their cache location has become outdated. Or has Firefox changed so much that this question is moot?

Running mac osx 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). I need to recover some files that are most likely still in the cache. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if Firefox still uses a cache on Mac OSX?

Comment: My brand new Firefox install on top of OS X 10.6.8 shows the cache at `.../Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/hm7m0wcn.default/Cache`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the MozillaZine Knowledge Base article [Profile folder - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Mac):

> Mac
>
> Profile folders are in one of these locations:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>
> ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>
> ```
>
> The tilde character (~) refers to the current user's Home folder, so
>   ~/Library is the /Macintosh HD/Users//Library folder.

This [section](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Folders) of that article describes the default cache location. You can also see where it is with this url: `about:cache` and change it by entering this one: `about:config` and then changing the preference named **browser.cache.disk.parent_directory**.

**Update:**

*I haven't updated the screenshot, but this still works in FireFox 15.0.1.*

Here's a screenshot of Firefox 13.0.1 running on OSX 0.6.8 (Snow Leopard). As you can see the cache folder has been put in a custom location on another volume using `about:config`.

[image: screenshot of Firefox 13.0.1 running on OSX 0.6.8 (Snow Leopard)]

Comment: Neat!  See "about:about" for all of the "about:" options.

Comment: Unfortunately, about:cache does not include directory information--at least not in my version of Firefox (13.0.1).  It shows entries and size, but that's all (sorry, can't post pictures in a comment, sigh).  

The website you mention (which is *really* useful--thanks!) says that about:cache is only good for, "Mac OS/Windows - previous to 1.5," which was a loooong time ago.

Comment: @ScottBiggs: I think you're mistaken `about:cache` only working on versions previous to 1.5. It works fine for me now on a Windows machine with Firefox 13.0.1 and displays its current size and location (as indicated in [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About_protocol_links) article. When I get a chance tomorrow morning I'll try in on my Mac running SL and FF 13.0.1. Regardless, you can see both what it is and change it by using `about:config`.

Comment: `about:cache` works fine on my 13.0.1 version on top of Vista.

Comment: Also works fine on my brand new 13.0.1 install on OS X 10.6.8.  Dunno about later versions.

Comment: @Scott Biggs; You _can_ always update your question with pictures showing what you see using `about:cache` (or there as well as in a comment put a link to an image hosted somewhere).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but after upgrades to both Firefox AND my os (Mavericks) this technique works: the directory is displayed.  Thanks for your help (check).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. That entry isn't listed in About:Config

Answer (score 2):

Go to `~/Users/"USERNAME"/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/` with `"USERNAME"` being the name of your home folder of your OS.

Then open the folder with a bunch of funny numbers at the beginning and ends with .default then open the cache folder.

Comment: This looks very promising, but I don't see any useful files cached here--nope, not even a .jpg is anywhere within this tree.  There are few subdirectories (startupCache/, OfflineCache/, and mozilla-media-cache/), but they are almost empty.

Comment: @ScottBiggs The local caches of browsers don't usually store the actual files. You can search for cached resources in about:cache or using an add-on like [CacheViewer Continued](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer-continued/).

Comment: Found the files with obfuscated names in ~/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>/cache2/entries/